# How can someone using egit/eclipse pull a remote branch that I created without using command line?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

This is probably quite simple, but I am just not familiar with eclipse. I have a `dev` branch that I have pushed to the server for review using the basic `git push origin dev`. My co-worker is new to git and would prefer to stay within eclipse to review the code. He has egit installed and I cannot seem to find a way to pull a specific remote branch. I know this is brief but I am more than willing to provide any information for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To easily review the changes, your co-worker can check out the remote branch as a new local branch and then look at the code and commits.

One possible way is:

1. *Team* > *Fetch from Upstream* to get the newest branches (or a normal pull, which includes a fetch)
2. *Team* > *Switch to* > *New Branch...*
3. Select `origin/dev` (assuming the remote is named `origin`) as the base branch
4. Click *Finish* to check out the new local `dev` branch

It can also be done via the Git Repositories view by expanding *Branches* > *Remote Tracking* and using *Create Branch...* from the context menu.

Another way is to find the branch in the *History* view (you may need to toggle the *Show All Branches and Tags* option, see [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#All_Branches)) and use *Create Branch...* there.